# Code First CTP: Multiple PKs or FKs

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In some instances, we may have PK/FK references duplicated, so entity A and entity B are in a PK/FK relationship, but 3 times.  So entity A would have 3 FK collections and entity B would have 3 entity references.  How does that work with the code-first template?  Do you follow the naming convention of Entity Framework model/database first approaches (EntityA, EntityA1, etc.), and it knows how to hook those relationships up, or is there an extra step, or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to define your classes like this

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityB EntityB1 { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityB EntityB2 { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityB EntityB3 { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EF Code First would create two tables (EntityAs, EntityBs).  By convection the EntityAs table would have a primary key of EntityAId and three foreign keys linking to EntityB called (EntityB1_EntityBId, EntityB2_EntityBId, EntityB3_EntityBId).

You can however override this convection by adding properties for the foreign keys and adding RelatedTo tags on the navigation properties.

For example:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public int MySpecialFkName { get; set; }
    [RelatedTo(ForeignKey = "MySpecialFkName")]
    public EntityB EntityB1 { get; set; }
}
```

If you didn't want the RelatedTo meta data in your POCO class, you could instead define the relationship in the OnModelCreating method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasRequired(p => p.EntityB1)
            .HasConstraint((fk, pk) => fk.MySpecialFkName == pk.EntityBId);
```